# How to open a *.pdf with Skim using start-process so that it has focus

Tags: emacs

Could anyone please give me a hand to open a *.pdf using Skim so that it has focus.  Skim opens the file correctly, but remains in the background.  I'm using a recent version of Emacs Trunk on an OSX machine.

If I insert something like "open -a" or "open -o" before the absolute path to Skim, then Emacs complains that there is no application by that name.  I've tried placing "-o" after the filename, but that didn't have any affect.

The following code is for Wanderlust, but I assume that `start-process` is universal.

```
(eval-after-load "mime-view"
  '(progn
     (ctree-set-calist-strictly
      'mime-acting-condition
      '((mode . "play")
        (type . application)(subtype . pdf)
        (method . lawlist-mime-view)))))

(defun lawlist-mime-view (&optional a b)
  (let* ((entity (get-text-property (point) 'mime-view-entity))
           (filename (mime-entity-safe-filename entity)))
  (mime-write-entity-content entity (concat "/tmp/" filename))
  (process-kill-without-query
    (start-process "hello-world" nil "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/MacOS/Skim" filename))))
```

---

**EDIT -- 1**:  Here is a simplistic function to help with diagnosing the problem.  I have created a *.pdf file and saved it as `"/tmp/test.pdf"`.

```
(defun test-start-process ()
  (interactive)
    (start-process "hello-world" nil "open" "-a Skim" "/tmp/test.pdf"))
```

---

**EDIT -- 2**:  Here is the revised working code thanks to the help from `tungd` -- greatly appreciated!

```
(eval-after-load "mime-view"
  '(progn
     (ctree-set-calist-strictly
      'mime-acting-condition
      '((mode . "play")
        (type . application)(subtype . pdf)
        (method . lawlist-mime-view)))))

(defun lawlist-mime-view (&optional a b)
  (let* (
    (entity (get-text-property (point) 'mime-view-entity))
    (name (mime-entity-safe-filename entity))
    (filename (concat "/tmp/" name)) )
  (mime-write-entity-content entity filename)
  (start-process "hello-world" nil "open" "-a" "Skim" filename)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `open` is the easiest way. However the definition of `start-process` is:

```
(start-process NAME BUFFER PROGRAM &rest PROGRAM-ARGS)
```

So you will have to use it like so:

```
(start-process "hello-world" nil "open" "-a" "Skim" filename)
```

Comment: I am beginning to think that there may be a bug somewhere.  Using the proposed code in this answer, nothing happens after the file gets saved with mime-write....  I have debugging enabled, but there are no errors being reported.  Using only "open" plus the filename brings the default *.pdf reader (Adobe) to the foreground with the open file.  It is possible to call an Applescript to bring Skim to the foreground after it opens the file in the background, but that should not be necessary if things are working correctly.  Hmmm . . .

Comment: To rule out potential problems, I created a simplistic function using only `start-process` and I added it underneath the original question.  The result is the same as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Ahhh . . .  You were very very close.  Here is the working code:   `(start-process "hello-world" nil "open" "-a" "Skim" filename)`.  Whenever you have a moment, please revise your answer and I'll accept it.  Thank you very much for helping me figure out why this wasn't working previously.

Comment: Sorry for not being correct. My point was just that the program name must be the name of the executables, not arbitrary string. Btw I updated the answer. Thanks.